# Array to columns in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I've built a functioning classification model following [this tutorial](https://kavita-ganesan.com/news-classifier-with-logistic-regression-in-python/#Saving-Logistic-Regression-Model).
I bring in a csv and then pass each row's text value into a function which calls on the classification model to make a prediction. The function returns an array which I need put into columns in the dataframe.

Function:

```
def get_top_k_predictions(model,X_test,k):

# get probabilities instead of predicted labels, since we want to collect top 3
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
probs = model.predict_proba(X_test)

# GET TOP K PREDICTIONS BY PROB - note these are just index
best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-k:]

# GET CATEGORY OF PREDICTIONS
preds = [
[(model.classes_[predicted_cat], distribution[predicted_cat])
 for predicted_cat in prediction]
for distribution, prediction in zip(probs, best_n)]


preds=[ item[::-1] for item in preds]
return preds
```

Function Call:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
category_test_features=category_loaded_transformer.transform(df['Text'].values.astype('U'))
df['PREDICTION'] = get_top_k_predictions(category_loaded_model,category_test_features,9)
```

This is the output from the function:

```
[[('Learning Activities', 0.001271131465669718),
  ('Communication', 0.002696299964802842),
  ('Learning Objectives', 0.002774964762863968),
  ('Learning Technology', 0.003557563051027678),
  ('Instructor/TAs', 0.004512712287403168),
  ('General', 0.006675929282872587),
  ('Learning Materials', 0.013051869950436862),
  ('Course Structure', 0.02781481160602757),
  ('Community', 0.9376447176288959)]]
```

I want the output to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uxLg.png) in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You function returns a list that contains a list of tuples? Why the double-nested list? One way I can think of:

```py
tmp = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    predictions = get_top_k_predictions(...)
    tmp[index] = {
        key: value for key, value in predictions[0]
    }

tmp = pd.DataFrame(tmp).T
df.join(tmp)
```

Comment: The double nested list is just how the tutorial that I followed did it. If there is a better way to structure the function I am definitely open to it!

Comment: I added your code to my project and it gave me the right format but it copied the same output for the first row to all of the other rows.
tmp = {} for index, row in df.iterrows(): category_test_features=category_loaded_transformer.transform(df['Text'].values.astype('U')) predictions = get_top_k_predictions(category_loaded_model,category_test_features,9) tmp[index] = { key: value for key, value in predictions[0] } tmp = pd.DataFrame(tmp).T df = df.join(tmp)